# Find Fourier transform of $f=\tiny\begin{cases}1-x^2,\:{x}\leq1\\x-1,\:x>1\\-x-1,\:x<-1\end{cases}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, distribution-theory

Let $f=\begin{cases}1-x^2,\:{x}\leq1\\x-1,\:x>1\\-x-1,\:x<-1\end{cases}$ (at the picture below). Find Fourier transform $Ff$.

I am hopelessly stuck, completely out of ideas.

- I've tried to operate by the definition but the calculations were too cumbersome.
- I've taken a first derivative but could not find a constant.
- I've taken a second derivative, too, but could not find one of two constants.

Could you please help me?

[image]

Comment: Direct is the way to go. Hint: if the Fourier transform is well defined as a tempered distribution, then you are more than welcome to consider the transform instead of $fe^{-\lambda|x|}$, then taking the limit as $\lambda\to0^+$ after computing the integral

Comment: Hint: $\left(\int_{-1}^1 e^{-i x\xi} d x\right)'' = -\int_{-1}^1 e^{-i x\xi} x^2 d x$

Comment: The function can be built from $xH(x)$ and $(1-x^2)\mathbf{1}_{[-1,1]}.$

Comment: @md2perpe, could you please clarify what is $H(x)$?

Comment: $H$ is the Heaviside step function: $H(x)=0$ if $x<0$ and $H(x)=1$ if $x>0.$